# PHP : Automatic convert of doc/docx to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, ubuntu-14.04, converters, doc

I'm using a LAMP server where users can upload their documents. If the file extension is .doc or .docx, I need to convert them to pdf automatically using php (the `exec()` function). I tried the methods I have found on Stackoverflow but none of them seems working.

The commands that work from terminal but not from php `exec()`:

```
>doc2pdf /home/xyz/xy.doc

>soffice --headless --convert-to pdf /home/xyz/xy.doc --outdir /home/xyz/
```

How can I solve this automatic convert problem using php? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What happens when you try the `exec` from PHP? Does the PHP user have permission to execute that?

Comment: I convert the files to txt too. I execute it using the exec() command and pdftotext, it works fine.